# A contain masking operation

Tags: pandas, numpy

Suppose such an array

```
In [8]: pd.Series(['testing', 'the', 'masking'])
Out[8]:
0    testing
1        the
2    masking
dtype: object
```

Masking is handy

```
In [10]: arr == 'testing'
Out[10]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

If check if 't' in the individual strings, nested iterations should be applied

```
In [11]: [ u for u in arr if 't' in u]
Out[11]: ['testing', 'the']
```

Is it possible to get it done with

```
arr contains 't'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible

```
s[s.str.contains('t')]
```